# How to reset and repeat this function triggered by a button by pressing that button again?

Tags: javascript, button

I have a function that chooses a random string from an array and types it in a paragraph. I trigger this function by pressing a button.

```js
var myArray = ['something', 'something else', 'another thing',]; 
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
var i = 0;      
var speed = 55; 
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < rand.length) {
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML += rand.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button next" id = "next" onclick="typeWriter()"> Next</button>

<p id="question"></p>
```

Pressing the "next" button triggers the typeWriter function, which chooses a random string from myArray and begins to type it in the paragraph "question". What I want to happen is, upon pressing "next" again (either while the typing is going on or after the typing is done), the text that has been typed already is deleted and the typeWriter triggers again, choosing another string and typing it in paragraph "question".

Comment: What about `document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = ""`?

Comment: I tried that, which succeeded in clearing the text. However, the function refuses to type a different string after that.

Comment: How can that be - or I do not understand your requirement? Please change your post, by replacing simple formatted code with runnable snippet.

Comment: I have edited your post. But I am not sure what you are actually trying to do in this code. Please change it so that it reflects what you currently have and try to better explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your edits; I've gotta learn the Stack scrip formatting. I have edited the question above. Is what I'm asking clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this?

```js
var myArray = ['something', 'something else', 'another thing',]; 
var speed = 100;

var target = document.getElementById("question");
var char;
var timer;
var sentence;

function type(){
  if(char < sentence.length) {
    target.innerHTML += sentence.charAt(char++);
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
  } 
}

function reset() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  sentence = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  char = 0;
  target.innerHTML = '';
}

function typeWriter() {
  reset();  
  timer = setInterval(type, speed);
}
```

```html
<button class="button next" id = "next" onclick="typeWriter()"> Next</button>

<p id="question"></p>
```

The `setTimeout` you have used implies that each time a character is "pressed", a new timer is started. My approach is to use an interval timer, which is simply writing the next character until the sentence ends or the typewriter is reset. In these two cases, the timer is cleared.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for your help! Could you explain how the timer and setInterval and clearInterval for that timer are utilized here?

Comment: Got it. Thank you for clarifying. I suppose a quick followup question would be, if I wanted to pause the typing by pressing another button, should the function it triggers define the speed variable to a huge value (and a resume button would make it 100 again), or is there a way to pause the interval approach?

Comment: @HelloWorld No. Just clear the timer only and recreate it when you want to restart it. But don't touch anything else. You can't change the delay of the timer once created.

Comment: Thanks again, this helped a lot to streamline my coding. This opened my eyes to using intervals and timers more when accomplishing tasks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are fetching random string then you need to write that code inside your function. 
please try below solution.

```html
<button class="button next" 
   id = "next"
   onclick="typeWriter()">
  Next
</button>

<p id="question"></p>

<script>

var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c',]; 

var i = 0;      
var speed = 55; 
   
 function typeWriter() {
   
  var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  
  if (i < rand.length) {
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = rand.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  else
  {
   i--;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works just fine when the strings are one letter, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the a,b, and c are just stand-ins for much longer strings, and with your script, individual letters from the string were typed and replaced in a random order. Pressing the button again didn't do anything... the function seemed to freak out.

Comment: how can you say, when clicking on next didn't work?

Comment: To clarify: when the strings were multiple characters, the function spit out a bunch of random characters that must have been contained in the strings one by one, deleting the last one then replacing it with a new one. When that stopped, pressing next again just typed a different random letter. I tried to address this by changing the "=" after innerHTML back to the "+=" that I have in my original script, but all this did was type a string that had random letters and arbitrary spacings. Pressing next again in this instance typed a random letter next to what had already been typed.